# create Multiple profile in my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, hierarchy, profile

i am creating an application in which i want to have different profiles of different hierarchy.Now,for different hierarchy they have different access permission level and the pages will be showing different contents.so, i want to know if there is any way to create application with multiple user views and features .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several way.First of all store the information according to user and their permission.You can make multiple layout for each user/permission.Then before showing the layout you can test user type and then can show accordingly.Or you can use only a layout and can add views dynamically on the layout according to user/permission